# If $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^n$ is injective, is $f(\mathbb R)$ contractible?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

For any injective function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^n$, is it true that $f(\mathbb R)$ is contractible?

I can show that for any Hausdorff space $X$ and injective function $f:[0,1] \to X$, $f([0,1])$ is contractible. But I am unable to figure out what happens, even just only for euclidean space as co-domain, if we take the domain to be an open interval. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $f(\mathbb{R})$ can be a [Lemniscate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemniscate) (or something more complicated).

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is a continuous map $X \to Y$, and either $X$ or $Y$ is contractible, then $f$ is nullhomotopic, i.e. homotopic to a constant map. So $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is nullhomotopic (the injectivity hypothesis is not necessary here).

However, the image need not be contractible. For example, consider the map $g : (-1.1, 1) \to \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $g(t) = (t^2 - 1, t^3 - t)$. This is an injective map with image given by the blue curve below (taken from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain) Wikipedia article).

$\hspace{60mm}$ [image]

Let $h$ be a homeomorphism $\mathbb{R}\to (-1.1, 1)$, then $f := g\circ h : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is an injective continuous map whose image is homotopy equivalent to $S^1$, and hence not contractible.

Comment: Ah yes , I was silly for not noticing that first thing you mentioned ... I am digressing your counterexample now ... how did you even imagine that $-1.1$ thing would work ...

Comment: Say if I asked whether for injective $f :[0,\infty)\to \mathbb R^n$ , $f[0,\infty)$ is contractible ... ? What would it be then ?

Comment: You just need the map defined on $[-1, 1)$ to get the loop, but you want the domain to be an open interval (so it is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$), so $(-1.1, 1)$ is a suitable candidate. As $[0, \infty)$ is homeomorphic to $[-1, 1)$, you can modify the above example (choose $h$ to be a homeomorphism $[0, \infty) \to [-1, 1)$ and restrict $g$ to $[-1, 1)$) to show that, although $f : [0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is necessarily nullhomotopic, its image need not be contractible.

Comment: @user228169 What's important is to have a picture in your head. Look at the loop in the picture provided in the answer - if you send $0$ to the end sticking out and let the remainder of the curve wrap around that loop, you will have an example.

Comment: @Michael Albanese : hmm ... so originally the natural choice for the domain was half open and half closed ... and you only did that decimal thing because of open interval requirement ...

Comment: Yes, that's right. Note, I did not come up with this example, it comes from the Wikipedia article I linked to. I knew an example like this existed, but I did not know of an explicit function that had the behaviour I was looking for.

Comment: @Wojowu : why do you say "loop" ... if it was a " loop" it wouldn't be injective .. but I can clearly see it is injective ( it is loop if you add $1$ to the domain though .. is that what you mean ? )

Comment: @user228169 With "loop" I mean exactly what you can see in the picture in this answer. It is not a loop in algebraic topology sense, it's a loop in that the image looks like a loop.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese : I wonder .. does such a counterexample exist for each dimension $n>1$ in the target Euclidean space ?

Comment: @user228169 You can use almost exactly the same map - take $g:(-1.1,1)\rightarrow\mathbb R^n,g(t)=(t^2-1,t^3-t,0,\dots,0)$. This will give a noncontractible image of an interval.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: Sorry to ask for this so late after the answer , but could you please provide a rigorous argument ( or a direct homotopy) showing as to why $g[-1,1)$ homotopically equivalent to $S^1$ ? Thanks in advance